# how to make 2 gridlayouts in the same panel in java

Tags: java, user-interface

i am making a board game and i used card layout to go through panels, (panel1,panel2,panel3)
panel 3 should contain the board(used in the game)and buttons so how can make these in the same panel without creating a new Jframe for board and buttons

Answer (score 0):

You create 2 JPanels, a board JPanel, and a button JPanel.  The button JPanel has a GridLayout.  The board JPanel has a GridLayout.

You put the board JPanel and the button JPanel inside Panel3.  Panel3 would have a FlowLayout or a BoxLayout.

You can nest JPanels inside of other JPanels.  That's how you can create complicated GUI layouts.

Comment: Okay how can i add then to panel3 boxlayout

Comment: panel3.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)  A JPanel is another Swing component.